# How would you calculate the next number where the sum of odd positioned digits is equal to the sum of even positioned digits?

Tags: number-theory, algorithms

A "nice" number is a number whose sum of even positioned digits is the same as the sum of odd positioned digits.

> For example:
> $12375$ is nice because $(1+3+5) = (2+7)$
> $9876$ is not nice because $(9+7) \ne (8+6)$

I'm trying to figure out, given a number $n$, how would you find the smallest nice number greater than $n$ without just counting up by one and checking?

I have no idea what to do, any help would be appreciated. It feels like there should be an elegant solution, but I can't see it... I thought for a while about permutations and finding all possibilities for a given digitsum but there's always testcases where it falls apart. Any ideas?

Comment: You could save $90\%$ of your work by counting up by $11s$.  All nice numbers are multiples of $11$.

Comment: Yeah, ofc, thanks! After trying some more, it seems to be an issue with carrying - my current idea is get the next highest multiple of 11 after n then divide it by 11 (let this equal x), then if any adjacient digitsums in x are greater than 9 get the leftmost pair and add one to the left one, then set everything to the right to 0 e.g. if n=2089, x=2090/11 = 190, 1+9 > 9 so replace 1 with 2 and set everything else to 0 leaving x=200, but this misses out 191 which is a valid x :( I should also clarify, the bounds for n are 1 <= n <= 10^100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $n$ be given

1. Let $a_ma_{m-1}\ldots a_1a_0$ be the decimal expansion of $n$.
2. Let $S_0=a_0+a_2+a_4+\cdots$ and $S_1=a_1+a_3+\cdots$
3. If $S_0<S_1$, find the minimal $k\ge0$ with $k$ odd  and $a_k<9$ or $k$ even and $a_k>0$. Set $a_k\leftarrow 9$ or $\leftarrow 0$, repectively, depending on the parity of $k$. If this makes $S_0\ge S_1$, set $a_k$ to the digit that makes $S_0=S_1$ instead and go to step 5. Otherwise repeat step 3.
4. If $S_0>S_1$, find the minimal $k\ge0$ with $k$ odd  and $a_k>0$ or $k$ even and $a_k<9$. Set $a_k\leftarrow 9$ or $\leftarrow 0$, repectively, depending on the parity of $k$. If this makes $S_0\le S_1$, set $a_k$ to the digit that makes $S_0=S_1$ instead and go to step 5. Otherwise repeat step 4.
5. Now $S_0=S_1$. If the current number $a_m\ldots a_0$ is $>n$, we are done.
   Otherwise, it is necessary to increase $a_{k+1}$. So let $n'=(\lfloor n/10^{k+1}\rfloor +1)\cdot 10^{k+1}$, set $a_m\ldots a_0$ to the decimal expansion of $n'$ and go back to step 2